# How can I obtain all of the OSGi bundles that my bundle depends on via Import-Package at runtime?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I know I could (in theory) obtain the `Import-Package` header for my bundle, parse it, and check which bundles export that package, but that seems error prone (and it seems like it might even return the wrong results). Is there no better way to find out my bundle's dependencies than obtaining my current bundle (via `FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ClassFromMyBundle.class)`), examining the `Import-Package` header (by calling `Bundle.getHeaders().get("Import-Package")`), and comparing the imported packages with packages exported by other bundles (again by calling `Bundle.getHeaders().get("Export-Package")`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not try to parse and compare headers. Instead, you can use the `BundleWiring` of your bundle to obtain the required wires of your bundle (based specifically on required packages).
 Then you can obtain the bundles that provide those wires to get a list of all the bundles that your bundle depends on via `Import-Package`.

[`BundleWiring.getRequiredWires`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/BundleWiring.html#getRequiredWires(java.lang.String))`(`[`BundleRevision.PACKAGE_NAMESPACE`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/BundleRevision.html#PACKAGE_NAMESPACE)`)` will return all the required [`BundleWire`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/BundleWire.html)s that provide packages to a bundle. Then you can call [`BundleWire.getProvider()`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/BundleWire.html#getProvider()) on each `BundleWire` to obtain the bundle that provides one or more of those packages. However, `getRequiredWires(BundleRevision.PACKAGE_NAMESPACE)` doesn't discriminate between packages imported via the `Import-Package` header and the `DynamicImport-Package` header. Since you only want to find `Import-Package` dependencies, you'll need to check whether the `BundleWire` is a dynamic dependency. You can do this by checking the directives of the [`BundleRequirement`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/BundleRequirement.html):

```
BundleRequirement requirement = bundleWire.getRequirement();

if (requirement != null) {

    Map<String, String> directives = requirement.getDirectives();
    String resolution = directives.get("resolution");

    if ("dynamic".equalsIgnoreCase(resolution)) {
        // The dependency was obtained via DynamicImport-Package.
    }
}
```

Here's a method that will do all of the above for you:

```
public static Set<Bundle> getBundlePackageImportDependencies(Bundle bundle) {

    BundleWiring bundleWiring = bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class);

    if (bundleWiring == null) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

    List<BundleWire> bundleWires =
        bundleWiring.getRequiredWires(BundleRevision.PACKAGE_NAMESPACE);

    if (bundleWires == null) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

    Set<Bundle> bundleDependencies = new HashSet<Bundle>();

    for (BundleWire bundleWire : bundleWires) {

        BundleRevision provider = bundleWire.getProvider();

        if (provider == null) {
            continue;
        }

        Bundle providerBundle = provider.getBundle();
        BundleRequirement requirement = bundleWire.getRequirement();

        if (requirement != null) {

            Map<String, String> directives = requirement.getDirectives();
            String resolution = directives.get("resolution");

            if ("dynamic".equalsIgnoreCase(resolution)) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        bundleDependencies.add(providerBundle);
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(bundleDependencies);
}
```

This method can be used to obtain the dependencies of the current bundle like so:

```
getBundlePackageImportDependencies(
    FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ClassFromYourBundle.class))
```

Comment: Good answer except for the very last part...using `FrameworkUtil.getBundle` is not the preferred way to get hold of your own bundle, and should only be used if you cannot get it another way (e.g. by implementing a DS component or a `BundleActivator`).